# Buscar ao menos um resultado dentro de um array mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Gostaria de retornar os posts do usuário caso ele possua ao menos uma das tags semelhante ao do post

**Por exemplo:**

- User tags `["react","c#","node"]`
- Post tags `["c#","sqlserver","asp.net"]`

Como o usuário possui a tag `C#` e o post também, gostaria de inclui-lo no resultado da consulta, através da documentação só consegui chegar até a parte em que retorno caso o `array` `user.tags` esteja *inteiramente* contido em `posts.tags`

```
   const user = await Users.findById(user_id);
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send('Usuário inválido');
    }
    const posts = await Posts.find({ tags: { $all: user.tags } });
```

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: Poderia trocar o `$all` por `$in`.

Comment: Deu certo!
Existe algum lugar que posso encontrar mais referências para $all e $in?

Comment: Sim, a documentação do mongodb https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) para alcançar o resultado desejado basta trocar o operador `$all` por `$in`

Uma solução possível seria:

```
const posts = await Posts.find({ tags: { $in: user.tags } });
```